Patterson & Hennessy, Computer Organization and Design, 5th edition, Question for Ex. 2.3
I am stumbling over the Exercise 2.3 of Chapter 2, i.e.:

For the following C statement, what is the corresponding MIPS assembly
code? Assume that the variables f, g, h, i, and j are assigned to
registers $s_0$, $s_1$, $s_2$, $s_3$, and $s_4$, respectively. Assume that
the base address of the arrays A and B are in registers $s_6$ and $s_7$,
respectively.
B[8] = A[i−j];


So, in the solution (https://github.com/dmohindru/cod5e/blob/master/solutions/CH02_Solution.pdf), it is indicated, that after calculating i-j and adding to the base address
sub t0, s3, s4
add t0, s6, t0

the word is loaded by
lw t1, 16(t0)

But why 16?
In my humble opinion, that should be either shifted left by two or multiplied by four
mul t0, t0, 4
lw t1, 0(t0)

to regard the 4-byte offset.
Or am I wrong?

You are correct.  The number of bytes of offset from the base address of array $A$ is $4*(i-j)$ and this multiplication by $4$ can be achieved by doing an sll (shift left) operation by two bits.  Here's the assembly code for $B[8] = A[i-j]$:
sub $t0, $s3, $s4   #temp register $t0 = i - j
sll $t0, $t0, 2     #temp register $t0 contains 4*(i-j)
add $t0, $s6, $t0   #t0 = address of A[i-j]
lw $t1, 0($t0)      #t1 = A[i-j]
sw $t1, 32($s7)     #B[8] now equals A[i-j]


Thanks, but this does not answer the original question of whether the solution given by the book is wrong.

@lordsnyder  The solution in the book is wrong.  First, i-j needs to be multiplied by 4.  But even assuming the instruction takes care of that (i.e. takes the position rather than number of bytes as the operand), an offset of 16 bytes does not make sense.

Thank you, that answers my question.
